# Automatically capture a order in PayPal

Tags: paypal

I'm integrating my application with PayPal and i found a problem.

I use PayPal REST API with **intent: "CAPTURE"**.

After I create an order in paypal via */v2/checkout/orders* POST endpoint and client pay for this order in *[https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token={TOKEN}](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=%7BTOKEN%7D)* website I don't receive any money or transaction on my PayPal business account.

When I check this order status it says that it is APPROVED but not COMPLETED, so i need to capture this order via *v2/checkout/orders/{TOKEN}/capture* POST endpoint. After capturing this order is has status: COMPLETED and i receive money.

Is It possible to automatically capture an order without any additional request to capture it?
Because when I use PayPal button It works automatically and I want to have the same result using REST API.

Comment: I find this quite confusing too. In the scenario of a simple payment, you create the order, redirect the customer, they pay and PayPal redirects them to your confirmation page. So when are you expected to capture the payment in this process? When their webhook notifies you that the purchase has been approved? In which case you're calling their API inside the thread that is responding to their call to your API? Meanwhile you're telling the customer it's all confirmed. Why is this two-step process required?

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible.

The capture step after approval (within onApprove) is always required.